# How can I make this image open in Iframe?

Tags: html, svg, iframe

```
 <a xlink:href="svg/agenda.jpg">
   <rect id="agenda" class="cls-2" x="911.09" y="102.61" width="91.5" height="30"/>
   </a>
```

The link need to be inserted using cordinates, because the page is basically a big image

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use below code to to display image.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%"
src="../svg/agenda.jpg" name="msg" id="msg">
<p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
</iframe><br />


<a href="../svg/agenda.jpg" target="msg">agenda image</a><br />
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I set the link position? x="911.09" y="102.61" width="91.5"

Comment: position: absolute; top: 50% left: 25%

you can change the percentage values upon your needs i prefer dealing with percentage though